# How to set initial directory in GTK3 FileChooser in Python?

Tags: python, gtk, glade, filechooser

EDIT: Solution found and shown in code below.

Python noob here.  I usually like to find answers myself, but I'm striking out on this one.

I simply want to set the directory the user starts in when FileChooser opens (rather than have the Python working directory).

This seems like such a simple thing and a common need, I am surprised and frustrated that I could not find anything in Glade (which I used to create the FileChooser), nor in any online GTK documentation.

So... how can this be done?

As mentioned I built the xml file with Glade and loaded it with gtk.builder.

Thanks much for any help

CODE WITH (A) SOLUTION

```py
def GetFile():
    import gi

    gi.require_version("Gtk", "3.0")
    from gi.repository import Gtk

    chosenfile = None

    class Handler:

        def on_destroy(self, *args):
            Gtk.main_quit()

        def on_OK_clicked(self, *args):
            nonlocal chosenfile
            chosenfile = window.get_filename()
            Gtk.main_quit()

        def on_cancel_clicked(self, *args):
            nonlocal chosenfile
            chosenfile = "CANCELLED"
            Gtk.main_quit()

    builder = Gtk.Builder()
    builder.add_from_file("mod_FileChoose.glade")
    builder.connect_signals(Handler())

    window = builder.get_object("FileSelector")
#HERE IS THE LINE IN QUESTION
    Gtk.FileChooser.set_current_folder(window, "/home/")
    window.show_all()

    Gtk.main()

    return chosenfile
```

I should add that in GTK API source where I found this, it states:

"In general, you should not use this function.  See the section on setting up a file chooser dialog[gtkfilechooserdialog-setting-up] for the rationale behind this."

So far I have not found the setting-up section with rationale for not using or better approach.

Source: [gtk API ref](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gtk/blob/3.24.24/gtk/gtkfilechooser.c#L900)

Comment: Hi! please show some research effort and code attempt. Even if its not correct, this is to get context of where you stand on this problem. 
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Thank you for responding.  I didn't include any of my code because it didn't have even a starting point for this issue.  BUT! while I was collecting links to show  research efforts, I found the solution and made it work.  ya!  I'll edit my post and add the code in case it should help someone in the future.

Comment: And btw, finding this was made more difficult because the GTK3 reference manual must have moved or be having a problem -- all links to it and pages of it are 404.  eg [link](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/)https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be okay to use the `set_current_folder` method as to the mentioned "setup section" [that can be found here](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk3/class.FileChooserDialog.html#setting-up-a-file-chooser-dialog-gtkfilechooserdialog-setting-up):

> Note that old versions of the file chooser’s documentation suggested using gtk_file_chooser_set_current_folder() in various situations, with the intention of letting the application suggest a reasonable default folder. This is no longer considered to be a good policy, as now the file chooser is able to make good suggestions on its own. In general, you should only cause the file chooser to show a specific folder when it is appropriate to use gtk_file_chooser_set_filename(), i.e. when you are doing a Save As command and you already have a file saved somewhere.

Addtional info: to look up docs, I use the `DevHelp` tool on Linux. Most Gtk docs (for python) for it [can be found on this github repo](https://github.com/pygobject/pgi-docs-devhelp). The offical online docs for Gtk3 should be [these](https://docs.gtk.org/gtk3/index.html).